# git pulled files give 500 error

Tags: git, centos, file-permissions, chmod

On a CentOS 6.3 server with WHM/cPanel:

When uploading files directly, I can access them in my browser just fine, but when I git pull them from the repository, they download but I can't access them (500 Internal Server Error).

I thought it was an ownership problem (on Ubuntu I used to set www-data as the owner), but from what I can see there is no apache user here, the files are run as the user itself. First thing when I git pull the files they have 644 permission (folder is 755, but files are 644).

Any idea how i can make git make them 755 on git pull?

Comment: Are you sure you need 755 on files? Are you sure it is the cause of the problem?

Comment: @wRAR: why would you think otherwise?  Apache will give a 500 if you try to CGI exec something that's not executable.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I don't see anything about CGI in the question.

Comment: There is no "500 internal server error" for files you have downloaded. This is a problem with some web server setup, i.e., you did never download them. How do you access the remote directory? What does `.git/config` say for the affected branches in the local repository?

Comment: @wRAR yeah, obviously I don't know that it was CGI exactly.  But it's obviously some web technology that requires the files be executable when you deploy them...

Comment: Thanks for the answers, yes, I did need to CGI exec the deployment script, that's why I needed exec permissions. Edward Thomson's answer with `git update-index --chmod=+x filename` did the trick, thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to commit them with the proper permissions in the first place.  Git should detect you changing the mode from non-executable to executable.  If you're on an OS that lacks an execute bit - say, Windows - you can tell git to add the execute bit manually:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x filename
```